# Length ordered subsets?

Tags: list, prolog

I'm trying to make a code that generates all subsets of a set **in order**.
That is, calling `subset([1,2,3], X)` should generate

```
X = [];
X = [1];
X = [2];
X = [3];
X = [1,2];
X = [1,3];
X = [2,3];
X = [1,2,3].
```

The internal order isn't all that important, only that the smallest subsets are listed first (i.e I don't care if [2,3] comes before [1,2], only that [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4917016/4265645), [2] and [3] are before [2,3]).

--

I've tried two approaches thus far. First I tried making the predicate myself...

```
subset([], []).
subset(List, []).
subset(List, [N]) :-
    member(N, List).

subset(List, [N|Rest]) :-
    !,
    nth0(I, List, N),
    findall(E, (nth0(J, List, E), J > I), NewList),
    subset2(NewList, Rest).
```

...but it doesn't even come close to working as intended. Secondly I tried making the powerset (using [this subset predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4917016/4265645)) and ordering with list_to_ord_set/2, but I couldn't get it to work either.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a not so elegant solution... it requires a cut and some builtins

```
subset(Xs, Ys) :-
    length(Xs, L),
    between(0, L, N),
    length(Ys, N),
    assign(Xs, Ys).

assign(_, []) :- !.
assign([X|Xs], [X|Ys]) :-
    assign(Xs, Ys).
assign([_|Xs], Ys) :-
    assign(Xs, Ys).
```

as noted by @Fatalize, we can avoid the cut, just forcing the empty list on first argument of 1^ clause:

```
assign([], []).
assign([X|Xs], [X|Ys]) :-
    assign(Xs, Ys).
assign([_|Xs], Ys) :-
    assign(Xs, Ys).
```

I avoided to swap 2^ and 3^ clauses, so the 'natural' order is still nicely preserved

Comment: You don't need the cut if you use `assign([],[]).` instead of your first rule? If you want to get rid of the last evaluation which outputs `false` for some reason you can just swap the order of the second and third `assign` rules. It changes the ordering but is still valid according to what OP wants.

Comment: @Fatalize: the cut is required to avoid duplicate solutions, and the anon var to accept sublists of Xs

Comment: I don't get it. I obtain the exact same results with those changes. Care to provide an example which requires the cut and the anonymous variable?

Comment: Yeah it works! I'll make it the accepted answer, but I'll check back in a few days to look for something "more elegant" as you put it.

Comment: @Fatalize: you're right, applying the changes you describe we get the solutions in inverse 'internal' order.

Answer (score 3):

Always also consider using [DCG notation](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dcg/info) when describing lists.

For example:

```
list_sublist(Ls0, Ls) :-
        same_length(Ls0, Ls1),
        append(Ls, _, Ls1),
        phrase(sublist(Ls0), Ls).

sublist([])     --> [].
sublist([L|Ls]) --> ( [] ; [L] ), sublist(Ls).
```

Sample query:

```
?- list_sublist([a,b,c], Ls). 
Ls = [] ;
Ls = [c] ;
Ls = [b] ;
Ls = [a] ;
Ls = [b, c] ;
Ls = [a, c] ;
Ls = [a, b] ;
Ls = [a, b, c] ;
false.
```

Another example:

```
?- list_sublist(Ls, [b,c]).
Ls = [b, c] ;
Ls = [_G511, b, c] ;
Ls = [b, _G514, c] ;
Ls = [b, c, _G517] ;
etc.
```

Most general case:

```
?- list_sublist(Xs, Ys).
Xs = Ys, Ys = [] ;
Xs = [_G513],
Ys = [] ;
Xs = Ys, Ys = [_G513]
Xs = [_G513, _G516],
Ys = [] ;
etc.
```

Comment: s(X): I really dig `sublist//1`. How about writing `( [] | [L] )` instead of `( [] ; [L] )`?

Comment: I am in general *very much in favor* of using `|` in DCGs, +1! Probably it is more readable though when the variable is not exactly called `L`, isn't it? Compare `[] | [L]` or the even slightly less readable `[]|[L]` with `[] ; [L]` or `[];[L]`. Since I really would like to use `L` in this case, I find `;` slightly more readable in this concrete case. I would definitely use `|` in cases like `[] | [_]`.

Comment: Got any data on the visual similarity of ASCII chars under difficult reading conditions? Sth like the jargon file "great runes", but not for uppercase vs lowercase, but uppercase vs uppercase. I guess "L" is bad when there may be any of "[|I_17" around (plus some more if we consider using *italics* for emphasizing sth)...

Comment: This would be extremely interesting! I currently have nothing formal about this.

Comment: There's something to it, for sure! Just look at `[_I|Is]` *under difficult reading conditions*... Maybe the UX people could help: eyetracking plus skin conductance measurements, maybe?