# How to get all consecutive sublists/subsets in Prolog?

Tags: list, prolog, substring, sublist

I would like to solve a simple problem, but even through I tried many different approaches, I couldn't find a solution for it. I am using SICStus Prolog (if that matters), and I want to get all sublists/subsets (I don't know which term is correct for this) of a list, which contains elements in succession. For example, if I have the list [1, 2, 3, 4], calling the **`sl/2`** predicate as `sl([1, 2, 3, 4], R).`, the expected result is:

```
? - sl([1, 2, 3, 4], R).
R = [] ? ;
R = [1] ? ;
R = [1, 2] ? ;
R = [1, 2, 3] ? ;
R = [1, 2, 3, 4] ? ;
R = [2] ? ;
R = [2, 3] ? ;
R = [2, 3, 4] ? ;
R = [3] ? ;
R = [3, 4] ? ;
R = [4] ? ;
no
```

The best result I could reach until now is:

```
sl([], []).
sl([X|Xs], [X|Ys]) :-
    sl(Xs, Ys).
sl([_|Xs], Ys) :-
    sl(Xs, Ys).
```

But this also gives me the following *unwanted* results in addition:

```
R = [1,2,4] ? ;
R = [1,3,4] ? ;
R = [1,3] ? ;
R = [1,4] ? ;
R = [2,4] ? ;
```

How should I modify my predicates so I can get the desired result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subsets in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912869/subsets-in-prolog)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When writing a predicate in Prolog, you need to think about what the predicate means, or what relation it is defining. The reason your predicate gives non-solutions is that you are mixing meanings in your predicate clauses. They don't all really mean the same thing.

You have the predicate `sl/2` which is intended to mean "sublist" (or "subsequence") but, more than that, means a sublist per the description you provided, which is a *contiguous sublist* (cannot have any "gaps" in it).

Now we can break down your clauses:

```
sl([], []).
```

This says *the empty list is a contiguous sublist of the empty list*. This is true, so is a valid fact.

```
sl([X|Xs], [X|Ys]) :-
    sl(Xs, Ys).
```

This says that *`[X|Ys]` is a contiguous sublist of `[X|Xs]` if `Ys` is a contiguous sublist of `Xs`*. This relation is **not** true. What would really be true here would be: *`[X|Ys]` is a contiguous sublist of `[X|Xs]` if `Ys` is a contiguous **prefix sublist** of `Xs`*. That is, not only does `Ys` need to be a sublist of `Xs`, but it needs to be only from the start of the list and not somewhere within this list. This is a clue that you'll need another predicate since the meaning of the relation is different.

Your final clause says that *`Ys` is a sublist of `[_|Xs]` if `Ys` is a sublist of `Xs`*. This appears to be true.

If we simply adjust to the above updated definitions, we get:

```
subseq([], []).
subseq([_|Xs], Ys) :-
    subseq(Xs, Ys).
subseq([X|Xs], [X|Ys]) :-
    prefix_subseq(Xs, Ys).

prefix_subseq(_, []).
prefix_subseq([X|Xs], [X|Ys]) :-
    prefix_subseq(Xs, Ys).
```

I offered the `prefix_subseq/2` definition above without explanation, but I think you can figure it out.

This now yields:

```
| ?- subseq([a,b,c,d], R).

R = [a] ? a

R = [a,b]

R = [a,b,c]

R = [a,b,c,d]

R = [b]

R = [b,c]

R = [b,c,d]

R = [c]

R = [c,d]

R = [d]

R = []

(1 ms) yes
```

An interesting, compact way of defining your sublist (or subsequence) would be using the `append/2` predicate:

```
subseq(L, R) :- append([_, R, _], L).
```

This says that `L` is the result of appending lists `_`, `R`, and `_`. The minor flaw in this simple implementation is that you'll get `R = []` more than once since it satisfies the `append([_, R, _], L)` rule in more than one way.

Taking a fresh look at the definition, you can use a DCG to define a subsequence, as a DCG is perfect for dealing with sequences:

```
% Empty list is a valid subsequence
subseq([]) --> ... .
% Subsequence is any sequence, followed by sequence we want, followed by any sequence
subseq(S) --> ..., non_empty_seq(S), ... .

% Definition of any sequence
... --> [] | [_], ... .

% non-empty sequence we want to capture
non_empty_seq([X]) --> [X].
non_empty_seq([X|T]) --> [X], non_empty_seq(T).
```

And you can call it with `phrase/2`:

```
| ?- phrase(subseq(S), [a,b,c,d]).

S = [] ? ;

S = [a] ? ;

S = [a,b] ? ;

S = [a,b,c] ? ;

S = [a,b,c,d] ? ;

S = [b] ? ;

S = [b,c] ? ;

S = [b,c,d] ? ;

S = [c] ? ;

S = [c,d] ? ;

S = [d] ? ;

no
```

We can reswizzle this definition a little and make use of a common `seq//1` definition to make it more compact:

```
subseq([]) --> seq(_) .
subseq([X|Xs]) --> seq(_), [X], seq(Xs), seq(_).

% alternatively: seq(_), seq([X|Xs]), seq(_).

seq([]) --> [].
seq([X|Xs]) --> [X], seq(Xs).
```

Comment: Note that this is called a [substring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring)/sublist but not a [subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence)!

Comment: Not sure why you do  not permit `[]` in `seq//1`. The empty sequence - that is pretty common.

Comment: @false generally I agree. Originally, I did have `seq([]) --> []` as a base case, but not `subseq([]) --> ... .`  In this context, permitting `[]` in `seq//1` results in multiple matches of `[]` in the solution set. Technically, `[]` satisfies the definition of the original predicate multiple ways, but I was wanting to avoid it in a "natural" way. I changed the name of `seq//1` in my answer to `non_empty_seq//1`.

Comment: Is it natural to use a misleading name? You can say `{Xs=[_|_]}, seq(Xs)` instead. With `Xs` of fixed length, this is significantly more efficient. And otherwise probably too (would need to measure).

Comment: @false Is `non_empty_seq//1` misleading?

Comment: That is fine. It's most natural definition would be: `non_empty_seq(Xs) --> {Xs = [_|_]}, seq(Xs).`

Comment: @false, yes, I see what mean. Thank you.