# Prolog: Concatenate 2 constant Variables with a dash

Tags: prolog, constants, ciao-prolog

My problem is, that I don't know how i can dynamically concatenate 2 constants in Prolog.
For example I have the following procedures:

```
word1(lys).
word2(ser).
word3(rta).
...
wordN(...).
```

How can I write a function or create a varibale which dynamically take values like [lys-ser] or [rta-ser-lys] depending on other variables?

Comment: Unification. `words_term(A, B, A-B).`

Comment: Thank you very much :) Unfortunately now i have another problem with this. If A = lys and B = arg-blu and I call `words_term(lys, arg-blu, C)` then C = lys-(arg-glu), but I dont want the round brackets around...I want C = lys-arg-glu :/

Comment: `lys-arg-glu` is actually the grouping `(lys-arg)-glu` since Prilog interprets the term left to right and `-` is treated as a binary functor. If you need a specific grouping, then you'll need to do a bit more work to change it. If you imagine the term being represented as a binary tree, then you are reorganizing the tree.

Answer (score 0):

A more complex solution could be this:

```
word(lys).
word(ser).
word(rta).

subset([], []).
subset([E|Tail], [E|NTail]):-
  subset(Tail, NTail).
subset([_|Tail], NTail):-
  subset(Tail, NTail).

get_terms([A],ST,S):-
    string_concat(ST,A,S).
get_terms([A|T],S,SO):-
    string_concat(A,"-",AT),
    string_concat(S,AT,ST),
    get_terms(T,ST,SO).

test:-
    findall(W,word(W),LW),
    subset(LW,LS),
    get_terms(LS,"",LT),
    writeln(LT).

?- test.
lys-ser-rta
lys-ser
lys-rta
lys
ser-rta
ser
rta
```

The predicate `subset/2` is taken [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912869/subsets-in-prolog)