# Why does it give me false as Subset's result?

Tags: prolog, subset

This code can not get me subsets it's always giving false as a result

```
possibleSubset([], []).
possibleSubset([H|T], [H|NT]):-
            possibleSubset(T, NT).
possibleSubset([_|T], NT):-
            possibleSubset(T, NT).
```

what to do then ? I have a project and I must submit it tomorrow so please help me as fast as you can

Comment: Am I correct in supposing that instead of `possibleSubset/2`, this predicate should be called `is_leftlist_a_subset_of_rightlist/2` and the list are not ordered in any way as in [ordsets](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=ordsets)?

Comment: Meanwhile, have a look at this question: [Subsets in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912869/subsets-in-prolog)

Comment: Nice topic but in fact I took the code from there and also it was working day a go but now it doesnt work

Comment: @AnasAshrad Well, it obviously doesn't work (just by reading it once) but what changed between a day ago and now? Do you have the code that worked?

Comment: Please provide some data that is `false` where you expect this to be `true`.

Comment: It should act like this
?- subset([1,2,3], X).
X = [] ;
X = [1] ;
X = [2] ;
X = [3] ;
X = [1, 2] ;
X = [1, 2, 3] ;
X = [2, 3] ;
...
It was working perfectly a day ago like I said and I didnt change a single thing in it except the name of it...I think this should not make a problem